# Use Handlebars with Ajax and Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, handlebars.js

I am learning to use handlebars and I want to use it in an AJAX call, according to my idea, once I get the data from the server, I compile with Handlebars and then I print in a specific div but it throws me an error.
Will my syntax be wrong?

```
<div id="get_art">
</div>

<script id="artists-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul class="artist">
    {{#each this}}
        <li class="i"><a class="i" href="{{url}}"><img alt="{{name}}" src="{{image}}"><span> ""</span></a></li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $temporal . "/assets/js/main.js" ?> "></script>
```

It is my js:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'http://localhost/test/api.php',
            data : 'endpoint=yahoo&results=2&wip=normal',
            dataType : 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#get_art').html('<img src="'+baseUrl+'/assets/img/loading.svg" />');
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#get_art').html('');
            var artistsTemplateSource = document.getElementById('artists-template');
            var artistsTemplate = Handlebars.compile(artistsTemplateSource);
            var $artists = $('#get_art');
            $artists.html(artistsTemplate(data));
        });
    });
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed [object HTMLScriptElement]
```

Comment: well, I don't know handlebars but the error should be really self explanatory, you are passing the script tag which `document.getElementById('artists-template');` will give you to `.compile()`. all I can tell you is to read on that method's docs again or double check what you think you are passing it

Comment: agree with Scaramouche. you're passing an html `element`, not the contents. if it's like mustache, it would be something like `var artistsTemplateSource = document.getElementById('artists-template').innerHTML;. check the docs.

Comment: try `artistsTemplate(data).outerHTML` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that instead of using a simple text to pass as a template you're using the HTML element itself. To get the text of the document you have the .html method of JQuery that you can use.

Instead of this

```
var artistsTemplateSource = document.getElementById('artists-template');
```

use this

```
var artistsTemplateSource = $("#artists-template").html();
```